# Wrong icon for Application folder

Tags: folders, dock, icon

For some reason, my Applications folder is using the Address book icon in the Dock.  How do I change this back to the correct icon.

I am using Mac 10.7.2 (although the problem has been there since 10.6).

[image: Wrong icon for Applications folder on Mac]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The icon is not "wrong" : You just have to select "Folder" in the "Display as" menu, not the "Stack". Do this by right-clicking on the folder and select stack.

[image]"

*PS : Just right click on the icon in your dock to make this menu popup.*